# Connecting Mongodb databse to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, connection

I have been trying to make a web app using node.js and express and decided to work with mongodb.
I am using mongodb node.js driver version: 4.3.1
I have tried all the possible ways to connect the node.js server with my mongodb atlas database.

My database also got connected using the following code in my db.js file:

```
const app = require('./app');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const Url = 'mongodb+srv://todoAppUser:<myOriginalPasswordHere>@cluster0.6lvjr.mongodb.net/myDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

MongoClient.connect(Url, function (err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var db = client.db('myDatabase');

  db.collection('products').findOne({}, function (findErr, result) {
    if (findErr) throw findErr;
    console.log(result.name);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

The above code works fine and gives the output as well.
But I want to use MVC (Model-view-Controller) framework for which I need to export the connection.

I made the following change in the above code:

```
MongoClient.connect(Url, function (err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var db = client.db('myDatabase');

  db.collection('products').findOne({}, function (findErr, result) {
    if (findErr) throw findErr;
    console.log(result.name);
  module.exports = db
    client.close();
  });
});
```

After the change when I try to access my connection (`const productCollection = require('./db').collection("product");`) from any other file of mine, it gives me the following error:

```
const productCollection = require('./db').collection("product");
                                          ^

TypeError: require(...).collection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Kush- Complete Data\exp-projects\nodeApp\productController.js:1:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Kush- Complete Data\exp-projects\nodeApp\router.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

May anyone please guide me and show a possible way out.

Thanks,
Kush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
I figured out, in newer versions of mongodb they have essentially changed the way of connecting node server to the database.
To establish a reusable connection (So that we can access the connected database from any other file), I created an async function in my `db.js` file where connection is established and then exported it. In the end of the file, I have called the function.
The code is as follows:

```
 const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')
    
    
    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://todoAppUser:<password>@cluster0.6lvjr.mongodb.net/myDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    
    async function start(){
      await client.connect()
      console.log("Connected")
      module.exports = client.db()
      const app = require('./app')
      app.listen(3000)
    }
    
      start()
```

and while calling it from another file:

```
const productCollection = require('./db').collection("product");
```

This code gives me no error and works perfectly fine.
With the help of the above code, one can use this conveniently while following the MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work, because modules are evaluated synchronously. Your callback is called asynchronously but your module has been alread evaluated at this time. Means `module.exports` has no effect and `require('./db').collection()` is not defined. Please see [Node.js Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for details.

To solve your problem, handle the connection stored in a module internal variable and export a getter instead of the connection variable itself.

```
// db.js
let client;
let db;

function connectDB(url, dbName) {
    client = new MongoClient(url);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.connect(function(err) {
            if(err) return reject(err);

            db = client.db(dbName);
            return resolve(db);
        });
    });
}

function getCurrentDB() {
    return db;
}

module.exports.connectDB = connectDB;
module.exports.getCurrentDB = getCurrentDB;
```

Then reuse your opened connection in other files like the following:

```
// other.js
const db = require("./db.js");

db.getCurrentDB().collection("product");
```

Of course, `getCurrentDB()` can only return a database connection if a connection has been established via `connectDB()` beforehand. So you have to wait for the resolution of the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).